# Salesforce Inbox Outlook Integration

Tags: integration, salesforce-for-outlook, inbox

Im trying to add '**New Opportunity**' to the Salesforce Inbox Outlook Integration dropdown:
[image]

I have added the '**New Opportunity**' Global action, but don't know how to make this available in the dropdown.

Can anyone help?

Edit: I am using Salesforce Enterprise edition.
I have added the new action OutLook_New_Opportunity

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old company admin had set up another publisher layout.
Once I added the 'New Opportunity' global action to that layout, it worked.

[image]